# Lightweight http server for OSX and Linux?

Tags: http-server, web-server

I would like to install a lightweight http server that can be configured as simply as going to the directory where I want to start a site, executing a simple command to tell it in which port, and that can easily be shutdown afterwards. In short, without having to deal with configuration files for this simple task.

I am aware of [ligthtpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/). It is simple but apparently still require me to write an (admittedly small) configuration file.
Someone recommended me [node.js](http://nodejs.org/), but it may be overkill.
Which are other alternatives for OSX and Linux ?

Comment: Welcome to the site Sergio! Have you tried Google? [Good questions](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) on our site usually require some effort on the part of the OP before someone will help. Posting what you've found so far and why it won't work for you will work to your benefit when asking questions here.

Comment: hi @MDMoore313 I have just added more details to my question. Hopefully it is better now.

Comment: What about hiawatha (https://www.hiawatha-webserver.org/) it's a lightweight webserver with a small footprint. Furthermore the author claim that it's been built with security in mind. By now I can only confirm this.

I have been using it for some projects and it's very easy to customize. In the most simple scenario you just need 2 lines in the config file.

Comment: there's also the [busybox httpd](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/httpd.c).  Written in C, optimized for embedded devices, callable as a simple command, cgi-capable, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pagekite will probably fit to your needs.

See https://pagekite.net/wiki/Howto/ShareFilesSecurely/#h2bfs for instructions on serving up a directory. For convenience, the command you might want is

```
pagekite.py /path/to/folder KITENAME.pagekite.me +indexes
```

Or for an even simpler solution with nothing special to install:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```